# android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row

Tags: java, android, absolute

i have created a recycle view  which contain list of image documents   for  image documents.  i have created some dynamically created edit text field.. when running code then 2nd  row edit text automatically appear in 7th row  . i have checked log for 7th row : in log dynamically created edit text is not calling..

i have created dynamically created edit text field inside absolute layout . so i have tried to hide absolute layout which not contain value of tree map  means array list size zero.

tree map data: value is array list of co ordinate of dynamically created field. 
[image]

```
<com.nm.esign.entities.ZoomLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/zoom_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fl_zoom_adapter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
       <!-- <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_img_document_name_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="name"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />-->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"


             />

        <AbsoluteLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_image_tempplate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </AbsoluteLayout >

      <!-- <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_img_document_name_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="name"></TextView>-->



    </FrameLayout>


      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_img_document_name_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>



</LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
  </com.nm.esign.entities.ZoomLayout>

adapter class:

public class TemplateImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TemplateImageAdapter.ViewHolder> /* implements View.OnTouchListener*/{

   // ArrayList<TemplateFieldList> templateLists;

    TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<TemplateFieldList> > myMap;

    AbsoluteLayout ll;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams param;
    int height_data=0;
    int width_data=0;
    private Context mContext;
    private Integer[] mKeys;
    String templateName;
    int key;
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams paramData;

    Entities entities=new Entities();
    Entities.Communicator communicator=entities.new Communicator();
    Entities.Server server=entities.new Server();
    String coordinateXRatio="",coordinateYRatio="",elementWidthRatio="",elementHeightRatio="",fieldType="";

/*
    *//*-------------------------------------------*//*
    private static final String TAG1 = "Touch";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")`enter code here`
    private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f, MAX_ZOOM = 1f;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // The 3 states (events) which the user is trying to perform
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // these PointF objects are used to record the point(s) the user is touching
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    *//*-------------------------------------------*/

    public TemplateImageAdapter(Context ctx, TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<TemplateFieldList>> myMapData ) {
       // this.templateLists = new ArrayList<>(templateLists);
       // this.myMap= new HashMap<String, ArrayList<TemplateFieldList>>();
        this.myMap=myMapData;
        mKeys= myMap.keySet().toArray(new Integer[myMapData.size()]);
        //mKeys = myMap.keySet().toArray(new String[myMapData.size()]);
        mContext = ctx;

    }



    /* @Override
     public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.document_list_item, parent, false);
         return new ViewHolder(v);
     }
 */
    @Override
    public TemplateImageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gallery_thumbnail, parent, false);


        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder,  int position) {
        coordinateXRatio=""; coordinateYRatio=""; elementWidthRatio=""; elementHeightRatio=""; fieldType="";
        ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.bindData(myMap.get(position));
        final int keytemp = mKeys[position];


     // keytemp=Integer.parseInt(key);
        key=keytemp;
        int pageNumber=1;
        String access_token=ViewTemplate.access_tokenTemp;



        try {
            communicator.urls = new URL(server.url + "/templates/getpageimage?templateId="+ViewTemplate.templateIdTemp+ "&pageNumber=" +(position+1)+ "&access_token=" +access_token );
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String img_url=  ""+communicator.urls;
         System.out.println("img_url=="+img_url);
      /*  Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.register_injury)*/
        Glide.with(mContext).load(img_url)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(holder.thumbnail);


        /*TouchImageViewgeView img = new TouchImageView(this);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ice_age_2);
        img.setMaxZoom(4f);

        setContentView(img);*/
        holder.documentName.setText("document name");


        if(myMap.get(key).size()>0) {
            System.out.println("key with data=="+key);

       ViewTreeObserver observer = ll.getViewTreeObserver();

        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                init();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    ll.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                } else {
                    //noinspection deprecation
                    ll.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
              //  ll.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                System.out.println("height="+height_data);
                System.out.println("width="+width_data);
              //  myMap.get("1").get(0).getAllfields_coordinateXRatio()
               /* String coordinateXRatio="",coordinateYRatio="",elementWidthRatio="",elementHeightRatio="",fieldType="";*/
                coordinateXRatio=""; coordinateYRatio=""; elementWidthRatio=""; elementHeightRatio=""; fieldType="";



               for(int i=0;i<myMap.get(key).size();i++) {

                   ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       coordinateXRatio = myMap.get(key).get(i).getAllfields_coordinateXRatio();
                       coordinateYRatio = myMap.get(key).get(i).getAllfields_coordinateYRatio();
                       elementWidthRatio = myMap.get(key).get(i).getAllfields_elementWidthRatio();
                       elementHeightRatio = myMap.get(key).get(i).getAllfields_elementHeightRatio();
                       fieldType = myMap.get(key).get(i).getAllfields_fieldType();

                       System.out.println("coordinateXRatio=" + coordinateXRatio);
                       System.out.println("coordinateYRatio=" + coordinateYRatio);
                       System.out.println("elementHeightRatio=" + elementHeightRatio);
                       System.out.println("fieldType=" + fieldType);
                       getParameter(coordinateXRatio, coordinateYRatio, elementWidthRatio, elementHeightRatio, fieldType, i);
                   coordinateXRatio = "";
                   coordinateYRatio = "";
                   elementWidthRatio ="";
                   elementHeightRatio = "";
                   fieldType = "";
                   }

        }


        });
        }


        ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       // ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



    public void getParameter(String coordinateXRatio,String coordinateYRatio,String elementWidthRatio,String elementHeightRatio,String fieldType,int i) {




        int left = (int) (width_data * Double.parseDouble(coordinateXRatio));
        int top = (int) (height_data * Double.parseDouble(coordinateYRatio));
        int widthData=(int) (width_data * Double.parseDouble(elementWidthRatio));
        int heightData=(int) (height_data * Double.parseDouble(elementHeightRatio));
         paramData = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(widthData, heightData, left, top);
         Calendar calendar;
        int year, month, day;
       // LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      if(fieldType.trim().equals("textfield") ) {
          EditText et = new EditText(mContext.getApplicationContext());

          et.setLayoutParams(paramData);
          et.setTextSize(6);
          et.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
          //et.setText("Dynamic EditText!");
          et.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c7ecfc"));
          ll.addView(et);
      } else if(fieldType.trim().equals("checkboxfield")) {
          CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(mContext.getApplicationContext());

          cb.setLayoutParams(paramData);
          cb.setTextSize(6);
          cb.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
         // cb.setText("ckb");
          cb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c7ecfc"));
          ll.addView(cb);
      } else if(fieldType.trim().equals("initialfield") ) {

          EditText et = new EditText(mContext.getApplicationContext());

          /*InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)mContext. getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
          imm.showSoftInput(et, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);*/

          et.setLayoutParams(paramData);
          et.setTextSize(6);
          et.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
          //et.setText("Dynamic EditText!");
          et.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c7ecfc"));
          ll.addView(et);




      }  else if(fieldType.trim().equals("securedfield") ) {
          TextView et = new TextView(mContext.getApplicationContext());

          et.setLayoutParams(paramData);
          et.setTextSize(6);
          et.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
         // et.setText("Dynamic EditText!");
          et.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c7ecfc"));
          ll.addView(et);

      } else if(fieldType.trim().equals("signfield") ) {
          CheckBox et = new CheckBox(mContext.getApplicationContext());

          et.setLayoutParams(paramData);
          et.setTextSize(6);
          et.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
         // et.setText("Dynamic EditText!");
          et.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c7ecfc"));
          ll.addView(et);

      } else if(fieldType.trim().equals("datefield")) {
          DatePicker et = new DatePicker(mContext.getApplicationContext());

          calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
          month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
          day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
          et.init(year, month, day, null);

          et.setLayoutParams(paramData);
          et.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        //  et.setText("Dynamic EditText!");
         // et.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c7ecfc"));
          ll.addView(et);
      }
        else {
          EditText et = new EditText(mContext.getApplicationContext());



          et.setLayoutParams(paramData);
          et.setTextSize(6);
          et.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
          //et.setText("Dynamic EditText!");
          et.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#c7ecfc"));
          ll.addView(et);

      }

    }

    public void init() {
        height_data= ll.getHeight();
        width_data = ll.getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myMap.size();
    }



    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public ImageView thumbnail;
        public TextView documentName;

        LinearLayout fl_zoom_adapter;


        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            ll=(AbsoluteLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.ll_image_tempplate) ;
            ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            thumbnail = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            documentName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_img_document_name_item);
            fl_zoom_adapter=(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.fl_zoom_adapter);
            ViewTemplate  activity = (ViewTemplate) mContext;
            ZoomLayout myZoomView = new ZoomLayout(activity);
           // fl_zoom_adapter.addView(myZoomView);



        }


        public void bindData( ArrayList<TemplateFieldList> templateLists) {
            ll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }
}
```

in log getParameter() method is not calling for row number 7.
issue is editext of row number is showing in row number 7 also and row number 3 edit text is showing in row number 8 also.. means old edit text is repeating in new row.

please ignore below line
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.
android Recyclable with absolute layout with dynamically created edit text repeated automatically in new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On BindView is called every time when Item view is visible depend on is it recycled or not. So every time bindView is called your layout is added in **AbsoluteLayout ll**. I suggest you to remove all views of ll by calling method **ll.removeAllViews();** on onBindview and than add views to that layout.

Will probably resolve your problem.

Comment: not working. i am using like this  :-                                                 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder,  int position) {
  
        ll.removeAllViews();
 
        holder.bindData(myMap.get(position));
        final int keytemp = mKeys[position];


   .........................................................

Comment: i am surprising ll.setVisibility(View.GONE); is also not working  in start of onBindview..

Comment: problem is whole frame layout of 2nd row  is showing in row number 7

Comment: yes its working fine... issue is declared AbsoluteLayout ll as global so i decrared it inside ViewHolder class and used ll as holder.ll                                              thanks alot for support.